# In what can this be decoded?

Tags: encryption, decode

In what can this be decoded?

Z_Z_Z_Z_XXX_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_ZXX|Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_ZZ_Z_Z_XXXXX_Z_Z_Z_Z_|Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_XXXXXXXXXX|XXXXZ_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_Z_AS46

Comment: Any additional information available for this text?

Comment: Its supposed to be a 4 word sentence and underscores which are important.

Answer (score -2):

Oh i know the answer to that.

It's simple actually

4 words. The underscores are VERY important.

With those hints try to figure it out if you can't ill help you out!